# How to change fontawsome class name with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

I want to change the icon after deleting row. Should I only use font awesome icon once in blade, then remove the class name, then add the class name with ajax?

### blade:

```xml
<div id="status-{{ $country->id }}">
  <div id="icon-{{$country->id}}">
    @if( getStatus($country->status) == 'Active' || getStatus($country->status) == 'Aktif' )
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i>
    @elseif( getStatus($country->status) == 'Inactive' || getStatus($country->status) == 'Pasif' )
      <i class="fas fa-minus-circle text-info"></i>
    @else
      <i class="fas fa-times-circle text-danger"></i>
    @endif
    <strong>{{ getStatus($country->status) }}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

### ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "DELETE",
    header: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    success() {
        toastr['error']("{{ __('home.delete.message') }}");
        swal("{{ __('home.delete.message') }}", {
            icon: "success",
        });
        $('#status-' + id).text('Deleted')
        $('#icon-' + id).attr('i').addClass('fas fa-times-circle text-danger')
    },
    error(error) {
        toastr['warning']("{{ __('home.error.message') }}");
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `attr('i')` use `find('i')`

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's `.attr()` function is used to change the element's attribute. It has nothing to do with it's children.

Replace

```js
$('#icon-' + id).attr('i').addClass('fas fa-times-circle text-danger')
```

with this

```js
$('#icon-' + id + ' i').eq(0).attr('class', 'fas fa-times-circle text-danger');
```